# Parsear cadena dinámica y reemplazar datos vb.net ó c#

Tags: funcion

Hola amigos algún experto en manejo de cadenas, quiero ayuda sobre este problema que tengo que resolver.
Tengo una cadena de texto dinámica por ejemplo simples operaciones matemáticas y un código dentro de los corchetes.
Cadena1="[013]*45.5+([087]-[015])"

Aquí deseo obtener el número que está dentro de los corchetes ya que mediante una función personalizada que tengo ya funcionado

Función obtenervalor(codigo)
Buscar codigo
Return valor
Fin función

puedo evaluar la cadena desde el inicio hasta el final y obtener un valor numérico y que reemplace los corchetes y codigo por el valor obtenido quedando de esta manera una segunda cadena.

Obtenervalor(013)=>devuelve 30.2

Obtenervalor(087)=>devuelve 11.3

Obtenervalor(015)=>devuelve 22.9

Resultado final:
Cadena2="30.2*45.5+(11.3-22.9)"

Comment: ¿Pero en qué lenguaje de programación? ¿Nos podrías dar más detalles? Con lo que tenemos ahora, no hay forma de ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Puede ser en vb.net o c#

Comment: mmm entiendo entonces voz necesitas que te hagan el código por que no has hecho nada ???...

Comment: Después de investigar encontré lo que quería y estoy usando IronPython para ejecutar una fórmula simple. Aquí tengo un problema tengo este codigo pero devuelve un valor entero y la parte decimal no aparece como lo solucionaria. algun experto en ironpython

Dim engine As ScriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine() Dim code As String = "11*86/100" Dim source As ScriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.Expression) Dim result As Double = source.Execute() MessageBox.Show(result.ToString())